# MIPS-64 supported operating system

Tags: qemu, mips64

Is any operating system available for `mips64` (with complete source code) which can run on `QEMU` as guest?
thank you

Comment: can u elaborate your query about mips64 ?

Comment: I want to run guest operating system with MIPS (64-bit) architecture. And i need to know that any kernel available for this with complete source code? Like Malta mips can be used but its source code is not available, only elf file are available.

Answer (score 0):

Just clone newest kernel source code from kernel.org. If u want to build mips for 64 bit malta machine then try below configuration.

There are tree `defconfig` available in `mips/configs` so u can choose for your requirements

`malta_defconfig`

`malta_kvm_defconfig`

`malta_kvm_guest_defconfig`

`make ARCH=mips (one of above defconfig)`

`make ARCH=mips menuconfig`

here  select `CPU type (MIPS32 Release 2)  --->`

here select  `( ) MIPS32 Release 1                    │ │`
       `│ │                   ( ) MIPS32 Release 2                    │ │`
`│ │                   (X ) MIPS64 Release 1                    │ │`
`│ │                   ( ) MIPS64 Release 2`

select `mips64`

next build as usual using your cross-tools chain

Comment: @marry is above one clarifies your doubt  or am i wrong in my understanding? .. comment so that people can understand your problem in betterway